# Eclipse Scout Neon Message box triggered on server side

Tags: server, messagebox, eclipse-scout

I am wondering if there is a way to trigger message box on server side.

My case is that I have some logic on server side of the scout application. In the middle of the process some decision need to be made. It this case I would like to trigger message box with YES, NO, CANCEL options.

The way my logic works it really hard to split it into two functions and call one first, ask question and call another with on answer. So this is out of the way for me.

If it is not possible to triggered message box on scout service, is there a way to "mimic" it. So call service method, in the middle pause it, go to client side, present messsage box, return to same service method and continue it.

Why do I need this:

I have dependencies graph (between fields) implemented on scout server side. 
After one field has been changed, the whole dependencies graph will be resolved. 
One node of the graph has some logic that need user interaction. Problem is that I don't know if this method will be called (dependent on a graph), and if after this method other nods will be called.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a very similar question few months ago:
[Scout Eclipse present optional message on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439006/scout-eclipse-present-optional-message-on-server-side)

MessageBox is a client concept (package is: `org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ui.messagebox`).

You need to transfert the data you need from the server to the client and intercept this information client-side to display the message box you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Jmini already said, MessageBox is a client concept. What you can do is sending back a status (from server to client), checking it on client side and show an appropriate message (box). But then you interrupt your service method and cannot go on where it stopped (alternatively you can throw a VetoException, but this interrupts your service method aswell, so same problem). In my opinion, it is also not a good design to 'request' a user interaction from server side, because in this case, the server side has to wait for the user to respond.
I suggest, if possible, to split your logic into different parts. At first, you execute the first part until you reach the point where you need the user interaction. Then you could save the current state of execution, return to client and show the message. After the user has responded, you should start the 'second' execution, depending on the user's input. This second execution should be started by calling another (new) service, which at first should load or restore the state of the execution saved before requesting the user input.